# N dimensional array index utility Improved

Tags: c++, unit-testing

This is a continuation from a [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/280673/n-dimensional-array-index-utility); I updated the code with the suggestions and added an additional iteration.

- Templates are not an option because of the usage: The objects are stored as a class members where the sizes are not known at compile time
- Iterators are not used, not even for `scan_kernel` because I could not find a way to introduce them; I'm still open to suggestions
- Because of the new constructor I've had some trouble with the rule of 5, and I'm not sure about the duplication either, but there is a usecase where a new object needs to be constructed from another with a different padding so this is the best I could support it..
- The biggest problem with this is I do not know how to test `scan_kernel`; Otherwise how could this be improved?

Thank you very much for the great suggestions so far!

header:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

class NDArrayIndex{
public:
  NDArrayIndex(
    const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& dimensions, const std::vector<std::int32_t>& padding = {},
    const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position = {}
  );
  NDArrayIndex(const NDArrayIndex& other, const std::vector<std::int32_t>& padding = {});

  /** @brief    Sets the position to all zeroes
   *
   * @return    Reference to the object
   */
  NDArrayIndex& reset(){
    return set(std::vector<std::uint32_t>(size(), 0));
  }

  /** @brief    updates the position of the object based on the given argument
   * 
   * @param[in]   position    The position to move the object to; Must be within bounds!
   * 
   * @return    Reference to the object
   */
  NDArrayIndex& set(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position);

  /** @brief    updates the position of the object based on the given arguments
   *
   * @param[in]   dimension     The dimension to set the position of; Must be within bounds!
   * @param[in]   position      The position to move the object to; Must be within bounds!
   *
   * @return    Reference to the object
   */
  NDArrayIndex& set(std::uint32_t dimension, std::uint32_t position);

  /** @brief    updates the position of the object to go to the next position in the buffer range
   * 
   * @return    The index of the highest dimension the step modified
   */
  std::uint32_t step();

  /** @brief    updates the position of the object to go to direction given in the arguments if the new position is inside bounds,
   *            throws an exception of the new position is not inside bounds
   * 
   * @param[in]   dimension    The dimension to move the object on
   * @param[in]   delta        The number of steps to move the objects position in the given dimension
   * 
   * @return    Reference to the object
   */
  NDArrayIndex& step(std::uint32_t dimension, std::int32_t delta = 1);
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position() const{
    return m_position;
  }

  /** @brief    updates the position of the object based on the given argument
   * 
   * @param[in]   position    The position to base the calculations on
   * 
   * @return    The value of the mapped index, if there is any
   */
  std::optional<std::uint32_t> calculate_mapped_position(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position) const;

  /** @brief    Provides the index of the current position in the underlying buffer, if there is any
   * 
   * @return    the index pointing to the actual position, if it is mappable to the internal buffer
   */  
  std::optional<std::uint32_t> mapped_position() const{
    return m_mappedIndex;
  }

  /** @brief    Tells if the given position is inside the indexing interval provided by the dimensions and padding of the object
   * 
   * @param[in]   position     The position to base the calculations on
   * @param[in]   dimension    An optional dimension parameter to help shift the parameter
   * @param[in]   delta        The number of steps to move the objects position temporarily in the given dimension for the relevant check
   * 
   * @return    true if the given position is inside bounds
   */  
  bool inside_bounds(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position, std::uint32_t dimension = 0u, std::int32_t delta = 0) const;
  
  /** @brief    Tells if the stored position is inside the indexing interval provided by the dimensions and padding of the object
   * 
   * @param[in]   dimension    An optional dimension parameter to help shift the parameter
   * @param[in]   delta        The number of steps to move the objects position temporarily in the given dimension for the relevant check
   * 
   * @return    true if the given position is inside bounds
   */  
  bool inside_bounds(std::uint32_t dimension = 0u, std::int32_t delta = 0) const{
    return inside_bounds(m_position, dimension, delta);
  }
  
  /** @brief    Tells if the given position is inside the indexing interval provided by the dimensions and padding of the object
   * 
   * @param[in]   index        The index object supporting the position to base the check upon
   * @param[in]   dimension    An optional dimension parameter to help shift the parameter
   * @param[in]   delta        The number of steps to move the objects position temporarily in the given dimension for the relevant check
   * 
   * @return    true if the given position is inside bounds
   */
  bool inside_bounds(const NDArrayIndex& index, std::uint32_t dimension = 0u, std::int32_t delta = 0) const{
    return inside_bounds(index.position(), dimension, delta);
  }

  /** @brief    Tells if the given position is mappable to the buffer range determined by the dimensions and padding
   * 
   * @param[in]   position     The position to base the calculations on
   * @param[in]   dimension    An optional dimension parameter to help shift the parameter
   * @param[in]   delta        The number of steps to move the objects position temporarily in the given dimension for the relevant check
   * 
   * @return    true if the given position is inside bounds
   */
  bool inside_content(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position, std::uint32_t dimension = 0u, std::int32_t delta = 0) const;

  /** @brief    Tells if the stored position is mappable to the buffer range determined by the dimensions and padding
   * 
   * @param[in]   dimension    An optional dimension parameter to help shift the parameter
   * @param[in]   delta        The number of steps to move the objects position temporarily in the given dimension for the relevant check
   * 
   * @return    true if the given position is inside bounds
   */
  bool inside_content(std::uint32_t dimension = 0u, std::int32_t delta = 0) const{
    return inside_content(m_position, dimension, delta);
  }

  /** @brief    Tells if the given position is mappable to the buffer range determined by the dimensions and padding
   * 
   * @param[in]   index        The index object supporting the position to base the check upon
   * @param[in]   dimension    An optional dimension parameter to help shift the parameter
   * @param[in]   delta        The number of steps to move the objects position temporarily in the given dimension for the relevant check
   * 
   * @return    true if the given position is inside bounds
   */
  bool inside_content(const NDArrayIndex& index, std::uint32_t dimension = 0u, std::int32_t delta = 0) const{
    return inside_content(index.position(), dimension, delta);
  }

  /** @struct IntervalPart
   *  @brief Describes part of an interval excluding the direction it lies on
   *  @var    position_start          the absolute starting position of the interval relevan part
   *  @var    steps_inside_target     the size of the interval's relevant part
   */
  struct IntervalPart{
    std::uint32_t position_start;
    std::uint32_t steps_inside_target;
  };

  /** @brief    Tells which parts of the provided range relative to the stored direction are mappable to 
   *            the buffer range determined by the dimensions and padding
   * 
   * @param[in]   dimension    The direction of the range relative to the currently stored position
   * @param[in]   delta        The size of the range starting from the stored position
   * 
   * @return    A vector of the parts of the interval inside the bounds of the objects buffer range:
   *            {position, size}:
   *            |->absolute position inside the given dimension, 
   *            |--------->number of steps still inside the defined ranges in the direction of the given dimension
   */
  std::vector<IntervalPart> mappable_parts_of(
    const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position, std::uint32_t dimension, std::int32_t delta
  ) const;

  /** @brief    Tells which parts of the stored range relative to the stored direction are mappable to 
   *            the buffer range determined by the dimensions and padding
   * 
   * @param[in]   dimension    The direction of the range relative to the currently stored position
   * @param[in]   delta        The size of the range starting from the stored position
   * 
   * @return    A vector of the parts of the interval inside the bounds of the objects buffer range:
   *            {position, size}:
   *            |->absolute position inside the given dimension, 
   *            |--------->number of steps still inside the defined ranges in the direction of the given dimension
   */
  std::vector<IntervalPart> mappable_parts_of(std::uint32_t dimension, std::int32_t delta) const{
    return mappable_parts_of(m_position, dimension, delta);
  }

  /** @brief    Tells the size of the internal buffer range, which maps every item in the NDArray to a one dimensional array
   * 
   * @return    Reference to the object
   */
  std::uint32_t buffer_size() const{
    return m_bufferSize;
  }

  /** @brief    Returns the number of dimensions
   *
   * @return    The number of dimensions
   */
  std::uint32_t size() const{
    return m_dimensions.size();
  }

  /** @brief    Returns the number of elements inside bounds under the given dimension
   *
   * @param[in]     dimension     the dimension to query the size for
   *
   * @return    the number of elements ( including padding ) the given dimension contains
   */
  std::uint32_t operator[](std::int32_t dimension) const{
    return m_padding[dimension] + m_dimensions[dimension] + m_padding[dimension];
  }

  /** @brief    Tells if the Object contains any padding at all
   *
   * @return    true, if any padding dimension is non-zero
   */
  bool has_padding(){
    return (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(std::count(m_padding.begin(), m_padding.end(), 0)) < m_padding.size());
  }

  /** @brief    Runs a given function through a kernel, starting from the stored position.
   *            The provided function is being called once every time kernel iteration hits the
   *            beginning of dimension[0] in the provided kernel. The arguments are called with
   *            the mapped index values inside this object, along with the count of elements available
   *            from the start until the end of dimension[0]. The position of the object is updated along
   *            with the position of the kernel during iteration, and is restored after iteration is finished.
   *
   * @param         kernel    the kernel dimensions to use for iteration
   * @param[in]     fun       the function to call for each kernel iteration.
   *                          Arguments: void(mapped_position, interval size)
   */
  void scan_kernel(NDArrayIndex& kernel, std::function<void(std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t)> fun);

private:
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t> m_dimensions;
  const std::vector<std::int32_t> m_padding;
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t> m_strides;
  const std::uint32_t m_bufferSize;
  std::vector<std::uint32_t> m_position;
  std::optional<std::uint32_t> m_mappedIndex;
};
```

source:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>


std::vector<std::int32_t> init_padding(
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& dimensions, const std::vector<std::int32_t>& padding
){
  if(1 == padding.size())
    return std::vector<std::int32_t>(dimensions.size(), padding[0]);

  if(1 < padding.size()){
    assert(dimensions.size() == padding.size());
    return padding;
  }
  return std::vector<std::int32_t>(dimensions.size(), 0);
}

std::vector<std::uint32_t> init_strides(
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& dimensions, const std::vector<std::int32_t>& padding
){
  assert(dimensions.size() == padding.size());
  std::vector<std::uint32_t> strides;
  std::uint32_t prev_stride = 1u;
  std::int32_t prev_padding = padding[0];
  std::uint32_t dim = 0;
  for(const std::uint32_t& dimension : dimensions){
    strides.push_back(prev_stride);
    prev_stride *= dimension + 2 * std::min(0, prev_padding);
    prev_padding = padding[dim++];
  }
  return strides;
}

std::vector<std::uint32_t> init_position(
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& dimensions, const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position
){
  if(0 < position.size()){
    assert(dimensions.size() == position.size());
    return {position};
  }
  return std::vector<std::uint32_t>(dimensions.size(), 0);
}

} /* namespace */

namespace rafko_utilities {

NDArrayIndex::NDArrayIndex(
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& dimensions, const std::vector<std::int32_t>& padding,
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position
)
: m_dimensions(dimensions)
, m_padding(init_padding(m_dimensions, padding))
, m_strides(init_strides(dimensions, m_padding))
, m_bufferSize(std::accumulate(m_dimensions.begin(), m_dimensions.end(), 1.0, 
  [](const std::uint32_t& partial, const std::uint32_t& element){ return partial * element; }
))
, m_position(init_position(m_dimensions, position))
, m_mappedIndex(calculate_mapped_position(m_position))
{
  assert(0 == std::count(m_dimensions.begin(), m_dimensions.end(), 0));
  assert(inside_bounds(m_position));
}

NDArrayIndex::NDArrayIndex(const NDArrayIndex& other, const std::vector<std::int32_t>& padding)
: m_dimensions(other.m_dimensions)
, m_padding(init_padding(m_dimensions, padding))
, m_strides(init_strides(m_dimensions, m_padding))
, m_bufferSize(other.m_bufferSize)
, m_position(other.m_position)
, m_mappedIndex(calculate_mapped_position(m_position))
{
  assert(0 == std::count(m_dimensions.begin(), m_dimensions.end(), 0));
  assert(inside_bounds(m_position));
}


NDArrayIndex& NDArrayIndex::set(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position){
  assert(position.size() == m_position.size());
  assert(inside_bounds(position));
  m_position = position;
  m_mappedIndex = calculate_mapped_position(m_position);
  assert( (!m_mappedIndex.has_value())||(m_mappedIndex.value() < m_bufferSize) );
  return *this;
}

NDArrayIndex& NDArrayIndex::set(std::uint32_t dimension, std::uint32_t position){
  assert(dimension < size());
  m_position[dimension] = position;
  m_mappedIndex = calculate_mapped_position(m_position);
  assert( (!m_mappedIndex.has_value())||(m_mappedIndex.value() < m_bufferSize) );
  assert(inside_bounds(m_position));
  return *this;
}


std::uint32_t NDArrayIndex::step(){
  std::uint32_t dim = 0;
  bool changed = false;
  while(dim < m_dimensions.size()){
    if(inside_bounds(dim, 1)){
      step(dim, 1);
      break;
    }else{
      changed = true;
      m_position[dim] = 0u;
    }
    ++dim;
  }
  if(dim >= m_dimensions.size()){
    m_mappedIndex = 0u; /* Overflow happened, start from the beginning */
    return m_dimensions.size() - 1;
  }else{
    if(changed)m_mappedIndex = calculate_mapped_position(m_position);
    assert(m_mappedIndex < m_bufferSize);
    return dim;
  }
}

NDArrayIndex& NDArrayIndex::step(std::uint32_t dimension, std::int32_t delta){
  const std::int32_t new_position = static_cast<std::int32_t>(m_position[dimension]) + delta;
  if(
    (new_position < 0)
    ||(
      new_position >= static_cast<std::int32_t>(m_dimensions[dimension] + (2 * std::max(0, m_padding[dimension])))
    )
  )throw std::runtime_error(
    "Current position d[" + std::to_string(dimension) + "] + " + std::to_string(delta) + " out of bounds!"
  );

  m_position[dimension] = new_position;

  bool new_position_is_inside_content = inside_content(m_position);
  if(m_mappedIndex.has_value() && new_position_is_inside_content){ /* m_mappedIndex has a value if the previous position was valid */
    m_mappedIndex.value() += m_strides[dimension] * delta;
    assert(m_mappedIndex < m_bufferSize);
  }else if(new_position_is_inside_content){ /* if the new position is inside bounds, then the mapped index can be caluclated */
    m_mappedIndex = calculate_mapped_position(m_position);
  }else m_mappedIndex = {}; /* No mapped index for positions inside the padding */
  return *this;
}

std::optional<std::uint32_t> NDArrayIndex::calculate_mapped_position(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position) const{
  assert(position.size() == m_strides.size());
  if(!inside_content(position))
    return {};

  std::uint32_t result_index = 0u;
  for(std::uint32_t dim = 0; dim < position.size(); ++dim){
    result_index += (position[dim] - std::max(m_padding[dim], -m_padding[dim])) * m_strides[dim];
  }
  return result_index;
}

bool NDArrayIndex::inside_bounds(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position, std::uint32_t dimension, std::int32_t delta) const{
  std::uint32_t dim = 0;
  return std::all_of(position.begin(), position.end(), 
    [this, &dim, dimension, delta](const std::uint32_t& pos){
      std::int32_t position = static_cast<std::int32_t>(pos);
      if(dim == dimension) position += delta;
      ++dim;
      return(
        (0 <= position)
        &&( position < (2 * std::max(int64_t{0}, static_cast<int64_t>(m_padding[dim - 1])) + static_cast<int64_t>(m_dimensions[dim - 1])) )
      );
    }
  );
}

bool NDArrayIndex::inside_content(const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position, std::uint32_t dimension, std::int32_t delta) const{
  std::uint32_t dim = 0;
  return std::all_of(position.begin(), position.end(), 
    [this, &dim, dimension, delta](const std::uint32_t& pos){
      std::int32_t actual_position = static_cast<std::int32_t>(pos);
      if(dim == dimension) actual_position += delta;
      ++dim;
      return( 
        (std::max(m_padding[dim - 1], -m_padding[dim - 1]) <= actual_position)
        &&(actual_position < static_cast<std::int32_t>(m_dimensions[dim - 1] + m_padding[dim - 1]))
      );
    }
  );
}

std::vector<NDArrayIndex::IntervalPart> NDArrayIndex::mappable_parts_of(
  const std::vector<std::uint32_t>& position, std::uint32_t dimension, std::int32_t delta
) const{
  std::vector<NDArrayIndex::IntervalPart> result;
  bool part_in_progress = false;
  for(std::int32_t delta_index = 0; delta_index < delta; delta_index += std::copysign(1, delta)){
    const bool current_position_in_inside_content = inside_content(position, dimension, delta_index);
    if(current_position_in_inside_content && part_in_progress){
      assert(0 < result.size());
      ++result.back().steps_inside_target; /* Increase the size of the current part of the interval */
    }else if(current_position_in_inside_content){ /* If the interval iteration became inside bounds */
      result.push_back({(position[dimension] + delta_index), 1}); /* Add the new part as a result */
      part_in_progress = true;
    }else part_in_progress = false;
  }
  return result;
}

void NDArrayIndex::scan_kernel(NDArrayIndex& kernel, std::function<void(std::uint32_t, std::uint32_t)> fun){
  assert(!kernel.has_padding());
  assert(size() == kernel.size());
  std::vector<std::uint32_t> original_position = m_position;
  kernel.reset();
  do{ /* Acquire interval inside bounds of the mappable buffer and call the function with it */
    std::vector<NDArrayIndex::IntervalPart> parts_inside_content = mappable_parts_of(m_position, 0, kernel[0]);
    if(mapped_position().has_value() && (0 < parts_inside_content.size())){
      auto& [start_pos, interval_size] = parts_inside_content[0];
      fun(mapped_position().value() - m_position[0] + start_pos, interval_size);
    }

    try{ /* Step in dimension[1], because dimension[0] should stay at position 0 */
      kernel.step(1,1); /* throws exception if the position goes out of bounds */
      step(1,1);
      std::cout << "^";
    }catch(...){ /* In case dimension[1] is out of bounds, step to the next position by the interface with wrap around */
      std::cout << ">";
      kernel.set(0, kernel[0] - 1); /* set the first dimensions position inside the kernel to the last */
      std::uint32_t modified_dimension = kernel.step();
      /*!Note: Because of overflow, the position in dimension[0] will reset to zero */
      if((kernel.mapped_position().has_value())&&(kernel.mapped_position().value() != 0)){
        for(std::uint32_t dim = 0; dim < modified_dimension; ++dim){
          m_position[dim] = original_position[dim];
        }
        ++m_position[modified_dimension];
        m_mappedIndex = calculate_mapped_position(m_position);
      }
    }
  }while( /* when the mapped position for the kernel points to the start of the first dimension, and the end of the others */
    (kernel.mapped_position().has_value()) /* the kernel is iterated through */
    &&(0 != kernel.mapped_position().value())
  );
  set(original_position);
}
```

test:

```cpp
TEST_CASE("Testing NDArray Indexing with a 2D array without padding", "[NDArray]"){
  std::uint32_t width = rand()%100;
  std::uint32_t height = rand()%100;
  rafko_utilities::NDArrayIndex idx({width, height});
  REQUIRE(!idx.has_padding());
  for(std::uint32_t variant = 0; variant < 5; ++variant){
    std::uint32_t x = rand()%width;
    std::uint32_t y = rand()%height;
    idx.set({x,y});
    REQUIRE(idx.inside_bounds());
    REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().has_value());
    REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().value() == (x + (y * width)));
    std::uint32_t elements_after_x_row = width - x;
    REQUIRE(1 == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width).size());
    REQUIRE(x == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width)[0].position_start);
    REQUIRE(elements_after_x_row == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width)[0].steps_inside_target);
    /*!Note: using width in the above interfaces because it is guaranteed
     * that an interval of that size spans over the relevant dimension
     * */
    if(y < (height - 1u))REQUIRE( idx.step(1,1).mapped_position() == (x + ((y + 1) * width)) );
      else CHECK_THROWS(idx.step(1,1));
  }

  REQUIRE(idx.buffer_size() == (width * height));
  idx.set({0,0});
  for(std::uint32_t i = 0; i < idx.buffer_size(); ++i){
    REQUIRE(idx.inside_bounds());
    REQUIRE(idx.inside_content());
    REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().has_value() == true);
    REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().value() == i);
    idx.step();
  }
}

TEST_CASE("Testing NDArray Indexing with a 2D array with positive padding", "[NDArray][padding]"){
  std::uint32_t width = 1 + rand()%20;
  std::uint32_t height = 1 + rand()%20;
  std::int32_t padding_x = rand()%5;
  std::int32_t padding_y = rand()%5;
  rafko_utilities::NDArrayIndex idx({width, height}, {padding_x, padding_y});
  REQUIRE(idx.has_padding());
  for(std::uint32_t variant = 0; variant < 5; ++variant){
    std::uint32_t x = padding_x + rand()%(width);
    std::uint32_t y = padding_y + rand()%(height);
    idx.set({x,y});
    REQUIRE(idx.inside_bounds());
    REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().has_value());
    REQUIRE( idx.mapped_position().value() == (x - padding_x + ((y - padding_y) * width)) );
    std::uint32_t elements_after_x_row = padding_x + width - x;
    REQUIRE(1 == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width).size());
      REQUIRE(x == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width)[0].position_start);
    REQUIRE(elements_after_x_row == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width)[0].steps_inside_target);
    if((static_cast<std::int32_t>(y) >= padding_y) && (y < (height + padding_y - 1)))
      REQUIRE( idx.step(1,1).mapped_position() == (x - padding_x + ((y - padding_y + 1) * width)) );
      else CHECK_NOTHROW(idx.step(1,1));
  }

  REQUIRE(idx.buffer_size() == (width * height));
  std::uint32_t x = 0u;
  std::uint32_t y = 0u;
  std::uint32_t reference_mapped_position = 0u;
  idx.set({0,0});
  for(std::uint32_t i = 0; i < idx.buffer_size(); ++i){
    if(
      (padding_x <= static_cast<std::int32_t>(x) && x < (padding_x + width))
      &&(padding_y <= static_cast<std::int32_t>(y) && y < (padding_y + height))
    ){
      REQUIRE(idx.inside_bounds());
      REQUIRE(idx.inside_content());
      REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().has_value() == true);
      REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().value() == reference_mapped_position);
      ++reference_mapped_position;
    }else{
      REQUIRE(idx.inside_bounds());
      REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().has_value() == false);
    }
    if(x < padding_x + width + padding_x - 1){
      REQUIRE(idx.step() == 0u);
      ++x;
    }else{
      REQUIRE(idx.step() == 1u);
      x = 0;
      ++y;
    }
  }
}

TEST_CASE("Testing NDArray Indexing with a 2D array with negative padding", "[NDArray][padding]"){
  std::uint32_t width = 11 + rand()%20;
  std::uint32_t height = 11 + rand()%20;
  std::int32_t padding_x = -rand()%5;
  std::int32_t padding_y = -rand()%5;

  rafko_utilities::NDArrayIndex idx({width, height}, {padding_x, padding_y});
  REQUIRE(idx.has_padding());
  for(std::uint32_t variant = 0; variant < 5; ++variant){
    std::uint32_t x = -padding_x + rand()%(width + 2 * padding_x);
    std::uint32_t y = -padding_y + rand()%(height + 2 * padding_y);
    idx.set({x,y});

    REQUIRE(idx.inside_bounds());
    REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().has_value());
    REQUIRE( idx.mapped_position().value() == (x + padding_x + ((y + padding_y) * (width + 2 * padding_x))) );
    std::uint32_t elements_after_x_row = padding_x + width - x;
    REQUIRE(1 == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width).size());
    REQUIRE(x == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width)[0].position_start);
    REQUIRE(elements_after_x_row == idx.mappable_parts_of(0,width)[0].steps_inside_target);
    if((static_cast<std::int32_t>(y) > -padding_y) && (y < (height + padding_y - 1)))
      REQUIRE( idx.step(1,1).mapped_position() == (x + padding_x + ((y + padding_y + 1) * (width + 2 * padding_x))) );
      else CHECK_NOTHROW(idx.step(1,1));
  }

  REQUIRE(idx.buffer_size() == (width * height));
  std::uint32_t x = 0u;
  std::uint32_t y = 0u;
  std::uint32_t reference_mapped_position = 0u;
  idx.set({0,0});
  for(std::uint32_t i = 0; i < idx.buffer_size(); ++i){
    if(
      (-padding_x <= static_cast<std::int32_t>(x) && x < (padding_x + width))
      &&(-padding_y <= static_cast<std::int32_t>(y) && y < (padding_y + height))
    ){
      REQUIRE(idx.inside_bounds());
      REQUIRE(idx.inside_content());
      REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().has_value() == true);
      REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().value() == reference_mapped_position);
      ++reference_mapped_position;
    }else{
      REQUIRE(idx.inside_bounds());
      REQUIRE(idx.mapped_position().has_value() == false);
    } 
    if(x < (width - 1)){
      REQUIRE(idx.step() == 0u);
      ++x;
    }else{
      REQUIRE(idx.step() == 1u);
      x = 0;
      ++y;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While the class is general, it is not good for vast majority of practical applications. Dimensions higher than 2 just explode in size way too fast and become uncomputable. It is usually better to figure out the niche you need and use properly designed class for it rather than use some random general inefficient class.

Comment: I don't target a specific architecture, where I'll use this is a framework targeting architecture search.

Comment: Note that C++23 will introduce [`std::mdspan`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan). You might want to see if that is something that would be useful for you, and implement something with a similar API. Also have a look at its [reference implementation](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Surprising behavior of the copy constructor

The second constructor takes another `NDArrayIndex` and a padding vector as arguments. However, because the `padding` argument has a default value, this second constructor is also a valid copy constructor. However, instead of making an exact copy of `other`, it will zero the padding sizes. Maybe this just really is what you want if you explicitly call the copy constructor, but consider that copies might be made implicitly at some point. It's much better to avoid any surprises, and have the copy constructor copy the padding as well. I suggest writing:

```
NDArrayIndex(const NDArrayIndex& other, const std::vector<std::int32_t>& new_padding);
NDArrayIndex(const NDArrayIndex& other) = default;
```

## Incomplete Doxygen documentation

It's great to see Doxygen comments being added! However, not all functions have been documented: it's missing for the constructors and for `position()`.

Some functions don't have all parameters documented, like `mappable_parts_of()` missing documentation for the parameter `position`.

You can also add a comment for the class as a whole, explaining what its purpose is.

I strongly recommend enabling the [`WARN_AS_ERROR` configuration option](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_warn_as_error) and running Doxygen as part of the regular build process.

## Use of `[in]` and `[out]`

Parameters that are passed by value don't need the `[in]` annotation. It is only required for `const` pointers and references.

You should also use `[out]` when you are passing non-`const` pointers and references. You missed that for the parameter `kernel` of `scan_kernel()`.

## Don't use exceptions for non-exceptional situations

In `scan_kernel()`, you call `kernel.step(1,1)`, and if this throws an exception you wrap around and try again. Consider that exceptions are free if you don't throw them, [but can be horribly expensive if you do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835817/are-exceptions-in-c-really-slow). So you should not use exceptions just to signal something that will happen normally in an expected situation. Create a `step_or_wrap()` function or something similar that does what you need in `scan_kernel()` and that doesn't `throw` anything.

## Use of 32-bit integers

As already mentioned by Toby Speight, there is actually no guarantee that `std::int32_t` exists, but I consider that highly unlikely these days. But more importantly, using 32-bit integers limits the maximum size of the arrays. For a high-dimensional array it might not make sense to have large sizes for the individual dimensions, but consider that their product might be quite large, and by even using 32-bit integers for `m_mappedIndex`, you limit yourself to arrays of at most 4 billion elements, which is not as large a number as it used to be.

There is also the issue that you have to use signed integers for some things, so effectively you only correctly handle arrays of 2 billion elements.

I strongly recommend that instead of hardcoding the use of 32-bit integers, you use [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) for indexes, counts and sizes.

## Adding iterators

> - Iterators are not used, not even for `scan_kernel` because I could not find a way to introduce them; I'm still open to suggestions

It's really not that hard to add iterators. Iterators are just a way to store and manipulate a position. Your `class NDArrayIndex` is pretty much doing everything an iterator does, so you could make it an official iterator by ensuring it conforms to the appropriate concepts, for example [`std::input_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator) (see [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) for a more explicit list of requirements):

```
class NDArrayIndex {
public:
    struct span {
        std::size_t mapped_position;
        std::size_t size;
    };

    using value_type = span;
    using reference_type = span&;
    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator;

    span operator->() const;
    span operator*() const;
    NDArrayIndex& operator++();
    bool operator==(const NDArrayIndex& other) const;

    ...
};

NDArrayIndex::span NDArrayIndex::operator*() const {
    std::vector<NDArrayIndex::IntervalPart> parts_inside_content = mappable_parts_of(m_position, 0, kernel[0]);
    auto& [start_pos, interval_size] = parts_inside_content[0];
    return {start_pos, interval_size};
}

NDArrayIndex& operator++() {
    kernel.step_or_wrap(1, 1);
    return *this;
}

...
```

This allows you to write:

```
NDArrayIndex begin{...};
NDArrayIndex end = begin;
end.set(/* to end of array */);

for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
    auto [start_pos, interval_size] = *it;
    fun(start_pos, interval_size);
}
```

Ideally, you would add `begin()` and `end()` methods to `NDArray` that return `NDArrayIndex`es, so that you can then write:

```
NDArray array{...};

for (auto [start_pos, interval_size]: array) {
    fun(start_Pos, interval_size);
}
```

Of course, I omitted several parts that are left as an excercise for the reader. You'll also notice it's a bit different from the usual iterators; those return references to the data in the container. You could make it so `NDArrayIndex` stores a reference to the `NDArray` it is indexing, so instead of the `struct span` I defined above, `operator*()` could return an actual [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) that directly references the data in the array.

Comment: awesome answer! Thank you! And TIL in the Doxygen usage :) 
Ideally this would work best as an iterator to an actual array, but the only usecase I currently have is the `scan_kernel` and maybe the `+=` operator, where a position is to be increased by a certain amount in the direction of a dimension, instead of only a single step.. Although the code you wrote seems intriguing, I find it difficult to use the class in that way for this usecase

Comment: for reference, the iterations I was talking about are taken from here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf
Here basically 3 `NDArrayIndex` classes are to be used